# What is this plant with five petal flowers and serrated leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-recommendations, plant-care

So I have had this plant for a while, it blooms with gorgeous flowers. 
However, I really want to know what is it called, how to better care for it and how to collect its seeds or propagate through cuttings if possible.
Any information would be great, thank you.

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

Answer (score 3):

This is *Impatiens hawkeri*, common name New Guinea Impatiens. It usually wilts when left in direct sun for a few hours, but otherwise it grows well even in very sunny places if watered regularly.

The easiest and fastest method of propagation is by cuttings. Just take a small part of the stem and cut the leaves, keeping only 1-2 mm of the petiole. Place the cuttings in a small pot where you water the soil daily. In the spot where a leaf was removed, a new branch will start to grow.

You can also keep the leaves if the cutting is more than 10 cm long (4"), but in this case you still have to remove the lowest leaves before placing them in soil.

I wouldn't try propagation by seeds because this crop is most likely the result of a breeding programme and in case the seeds are viable, they are likely to turn out different than what you have now.

I think this is a plant easy to experiment with: if watered too much, the stem will become mushy, if watered to little, the leaves will start to wilt. If you don't have any problems until now, keep doing the same.